# Determine the outer measure $\mu^{*}$ induced by $\mu$ and the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable subsets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

For the following two collections of subsets $S$, where the set function $\mu: S \to [0,\infty]$, I need to determine the outer measure $\mu^{*}$ induced by $\mu$ and the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets:

1. On the collection $S = \{\emptyset, [1,2] \}$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, where $\mu: S \to [0,\infty]$ is defined to be $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$, $\mu([1,2])=1$.
2. On the collection $S$ of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mu: S \to [0,\infty]$ is defined by setting $\mu(A)$ to be the number of integer points in $A \in S$.

I assume that the first one is easier than the second.  I'm not even entirely sure how $\mu(A)$ is being defined, but it seems kind of like a counting measure.

I've never done either of these types of problems before, and am therefore at a loss as to how to approach them.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably just before this was the discussion of how to define $\mu^*$ from $\mu$.  Then these exercises are to get you do carry out that definition, and thereby maybe begin to understand it.  We cannot do it for you without seeing the exact definitions for $\mu^*$ in your book.  But even in that case, you should show us what you can do, and where you get stuck.

Comment: **Hint**: Assuming you are using the standard method to define $\mu^*$ from $\mu$. 1. For any $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $\mu*(\emptyset)=0$;  $\mu^*(A)= 1$, if $A\neq \emptyset$ and $A\subseteq [1,2]$; $\mu^*(A)= +\infty$, if $A\neq \emptyset$ and $A\nsubseteq [1,2]$. Moreover, 
 $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable iff $A=\emptyset$ or $[1,2]\subseteq A$. 
 2.  For any $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $\mu^*(A)=\mu(A)=$ number of integer in $A$. Moreover, any $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is $\mu^*$-measurable. Now, can you apply the definitions of $\mu^*$ and of $\mu^*$-measurable to confirm / prove these results?

Comment: @Ramiro, there is a theorem: "Let $S$ be a collection of subsets of a set $X$ and $\mu:S \to [0, \infty]$ a set function.  Define $\mu^{*}(\emptyset) = 0$ and for $E \subset X$, $E \neq \emptyset$, define $\mu^{*}(E)=\inf \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_{k})$, where the infimum is taken over all countable collections $\{ E_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of sets in $S$ that cover $E$.  Then the set function $\mu^{*}: 2^{X} \to [0,\infty]$ is an outer measure called the outer measure induced by $\mu$". So, I'm guessing for 1., since there's only $[1,2]$, and $\emptyset$, $\inf \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu (E_{k})=1$?

Comment: Actually what you wrote is the definition of $\mu^*$ from $\mu$.  Yes, you need to use this definition.  In 1. you have three cases. Apply the defintion to each case. In 2. you have just one case.

Comment: @Ramiro, by three cases, you mean when $A = \emptyset$, $A \neq \emptyset$ but $A \subseteq [1,2]$, and $A \neq \emptyset$ but $A \not\subseteq [1,2]$ that you wrote out above?

Comment: @Ramiro, I'm going to need you to explain to me why $A$ is $\mu^{*}$-measurable iff $A = \emptyset$ or $[1,2]\subseteq A$. I'm trying to see how the definition of a $\mu^{*}$-measurable set $E$ ($E$ is $\mu^{*}$-measurable provided for every subset $A$ of $X$, $\mu^{*}(A) = \mu^{*}(A \cap E) + \mu^{*}(A \cap E^{c})$) gives us that.

Comment: Yes, those are the three cases.

Comment: @Ramiro, what about my other question?

Comment: I apologuise. Actually in 1. $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable iff $[1,2]\subseteq A$ or $[1,2] \subseteq A^c$. ($A=\emptyset$ is just a special case of $[1,2] \subseteq A^c$).

Comment: @Ramiro, right, because those are the only two ways you can show it using the criterion for $\mu^{*}$-measurability I gave above.

Comment: Do you see how to prove in 1. that $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable iff $[1,2]\subseteq A$ or $[1,2] \subseteq A^c$?

Comment: @Ramiro, If $[1,2] \subseteq A$, then $[1,2] \cap A^{c} = \emptyset$, so $\mu^{*}([1,2] \cap A^{c}) = 0$. Because $[1,2] \subseteq A$, $[1,2] \cap A = [1,2]$, so $\mu^{*}([1,2] \cap A) = \mu^{*}([1,2]) = 1$. Therefore, we have $\mu^{*}([1,2]) = \mu^{*}([1,2] \cap A) + \mu^{*}([1,2] \cap A^{c})$? (Similar for $[1,2] \subseteq A^{c}$) Is that right?

Comment: Great. So you proved that  $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable if $[1,2]\subseteq E$ or $[1,2]\subseteq E^c$. And the "only if" part?

Comment: @Ramiro, suppose $E$ is $\mu^{*}$-measurable, then since $[1,2] \subseteq X$, $\mu^{*}([1,2]) \geq u^{*}([1,2])\cap E) + \mu^{*}([1,2] \cap E^{c})$. But, I don't know where to go after that.

Comment: It is easy to show that $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable provided for every subset $A$ of $X$, 
such that $\mu^*(A) <+\infty$, $\mu^*(A)\geq \mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A\cap E^c)$.  
In 1. $\mu^*(A) <+\infty$ iff $A\subseteq [1,2]$. So we only need to test $E$ against 
subsets of $[1,2]$ and then the only way for the condition to hold is either  
$A\subseteq E$ or $A\subseteq E^c$. Since $A$ is an arbitrary subset of $[1,2]$, 
we have $[1,2]\subseteq E$ or $[1,2]\subseteq E^c$.

Comment: I edited it. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Ramiro, yes, thank you! Let me finish writing this up and I'll start on the second part.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S={\phi, [1,2]}$, $\mu(\phi)=0$, $\mu([1,2])=1$ as you indicated.

By definition of outer measure, for any $E \subset X$, $\mu^*(E)=\inf{\sum \mu(E_k)}$ such that $E \subset \cup E_k$.

Then, for arbitrary $E$: if $E = \phi$, $\mu^*(E)=0$ (since it is covered by $\cup \phi$); if $E\subset[1,2]$, $\mu^*(E)=1$ (since it is covered by $[1,2] \cup \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}\phi$; otherwise $\mu^*(E)=\infty$ (since no infimum exists).

To determine the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets, recall that $E$ is measurable iff for any $A \subset \bf{R}$, $\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \cap E^c)$.
This statement is trivial if $A = \phi$ or $A$ not contained in $[0,1]$.
Therefore consider $A \subset [1,2]$.
Then $\mu^*(A) = 1 = \mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \cap E^c)$ if and only if $A \cap E = \phi$ or $A \cap E^c = \phi$.
Thus, $E$ is measurable if and only if $[1,2] \subset E$ or $E \cap [1,2] = \phi$.